# What does this operator $\odot$ mean

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, surfaces

I read [this](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Darboux_frame#/Principal_curves) about the second fundamental form in Wikipedia and I’ve no idea what does $\odot$ mean? Does anybody know?
$$II=-dN\cdot dP=\omega^3_1\odot\omega^1+\omega^3_2\odot\omega^2$$

Comment: This is the symmetric tensor product, see wikipedia for a definition:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor#Symmetric_product

Comment: @Squirtle But $\omega^3_i$ and $\omega^i$ are both numbers, components of tensors, not tensors themselves.

Comment: No, $\omega^3_1, \omega^3_2, \omega^1, \omega^2$ are all $1$-tensors and not components of tensors.

Comment: Hadamard (elementwise) product? from https://d2l.ai/chapter_notation/index.html